# How can I make all the inputs inside my td's editable for the row the edit button was clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm very new to web dev and I'm sure this should be simple but I can't figure it out. I'm  trying to make all inputs in a table row editable on click of the edit link. I'm not using jquery so would like a pure js solution if possible.

The table structure is below and the edit link is calling UpdateTableRow();

```
<HTML>
  <head>
     <script src="/classes.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/">
      <table id="tbl-classes">
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>year</th>
          <th>size</th>
          <th>active</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!--Loop through all sql rows and add the data to the tables, use index to numerate cell id's-->
          <% data.forEach((row, index) => { %>
              <td id="td-name-<%= index + 1 %>"><input readonly id="inp-name-<%= index + 1 %>" type="text" name="name" value= <%= row.name %> /></td>
              <td id="td-year-<%= index + 1 %>"><input readonly id="inp-year-<%= index + 1 %>" type="text" name="year" value= <%= row.year %> /></td>
              <td id="td-size-<%= index + 1 %>"><input readonly id="inp-size-<%= index + 1 %>" type="text" name="size" value= <%= row.size %> /></td>
              <td id="td-active-<%= index + 1 %>"><input readonly id="inp-active-<%= index +1 %>" type="text" name="active" value= <%= row.active %> /></td>
              <td id="td-new-<%= index + 1 %>"><input readonly id="inp-new-<%= index +1 %>" type="text" name="new" class="new" value= '0' /></td>
              <td id="td-update-<%= index + 1 %>"><input readonly id="inp-update-<%= index +1 %>" type="text" name="update" class="update" value= '0' /></td>
              <td id="td-edit-<%= index + 1 %>" class="postcell"><a id="td-edit-<%= index + 1 %>" href="#" onclick= "UpdateTableRow(this);return false;">edit</href></td>
              <td id="td-delete-<%= index + 1 %>"class="postcell"><a id="td-delete-<%= index + 1 %>" href>delete</href></td>
        </tr>
          <% }) %>
      </table>
    </form>
   </body>
<HTML>
```

At the moment my updateTableRow() function is outputting a lot to the console so I can figure out what's going on but I'm a bit stuck now.  The desired result is to update all the readOnly attributes for each Input element to readOnly=false as this should make the input editable?
UpdateTableRow() in /classes.js

```
function UpdateTableRow(object){
    console.log(object.closest('tr'));
    var row = object.closest('tr');
    console.log(row.cells.length);
    for(i=0; i < row.cells.length; i++){
            console.log(row.cells[i].inputID("inp-name-)" + (i)));
    }
 }
```

Rendered HTML Table Code

```
<form method="POST" action="/classes">
      <button onclick="addNewRoomTableRecord()" type="button" name="+" autofocus="">+</button>
      <input id="save-btn" type="submit" value="V">
      <table id="tbl-classes">
        <tbody><tr>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>School Year</th>
          <th>Class Size</th>
          <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!--Loop through all sql rows and add the data to the tables, use index to numerate cell id's-->
          
              <td id="td-name-1"><input readonly="" id="inp-name-1" type="text" name="name" value="1A"></td>
              <td id="td-year-1"><input readonly="" id="inp-year-1" type="text" name="year" value="1"></td>
              <td id="td-size-1"><input readonly="" id="inp-size-1" type="text" name="size" value="30"></td>
              <td id="td-active-1"><input readonly="" id="inp-active-1" type="text" name="active" value="1"></td>
              <td id="td-new-1"><input readonly="" id="inp-new-1" type="text" name="new" class="new" value="0"></td>
              <td id="td-update-1"><input readonly="" id="inp-update-1" type="text" name="update" class="update" value="0"></td>
              <td id="td-edit-1" class="postcell"><a id="td-edit-1" href="#" onclick="UpdateTableRow(this);return false;">edit</a></td>
              <td id="td-delete-1" class="postcell"><a id="td-delete-1" href="">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
          
              <tr><td id="td-name-2"><input readonly="" id="inp-name-2" type="text" name="name" value="1B"></td>
              <td id="td-year-2"><input readonly="" id="inp-year-2" type="text" name="year" value="1"></td>
              <td id="td-size-2"><input readonly="" id="inp-size-2" type="text" name="size" value="30"></td>
              <td id="td-active-2"><input readonly="" id="inp-active-2" type="text" name="active" value="1"></td>
              <td id="td-new-2"><input readonly="" id="inp-new-2" type="text" name="new" class="new" value="0"></td>
              <td id="td-update-2"><input readonly="" id="inp-update-2" type="text" name="update" class="update" value="0"></td>
              <td id="td-edit-2" class="postcell"><a id="td-edit-2" href="#" onclick="UpdateTableRow(this);return false;">edit</a></td>
              <td id="td-delete-2" class="postcell"><a id="td-delete-2" href="">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
          
              <tr><td id="td-name-3"><input readonly="" id="inp-name-3" type="text" name="name" value="1C"></td>
              <td id="td-year-3"><input readonly="" id="inp-year-3" type="text" name="year" value="1"></td>
              <td id="td-size-3"><input readonly="" id="inp-size-3" type="text" name="size" value="30"></td>
              <td id="td-active-3"><input readonly="" id="inp-active-3" type="text" name="active" value="1"></td>
              <td id="td-new-3"><input readonly="" id="inp-new-3" type="text" name="new" class="new" value="0"></td>
              <td id="td-update-3"><input readonly="" id="inp-update-3" type="text" name="update" class="update" value="0"></td>
              <td id="td-edit-3" class="postcell"><a id="td-edit-3" href="#" onclick="UpdateTableRow(this);return false;">edit</a></td>
              <td id="td-delete-3" class="postcell"><a id="td-delete-3" href="">delete</a></td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody></table>
    </form>
```

[Rendered Table with console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq05M.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the rendered HTML that your browser sees, instead of the PHP template/view? Ideally the HTML of the `<table>`, with one or two rows of data.

Comment: @DavidThomas. Done Let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to apologise: I meant could you post the HTML (as text, in your question), because the PHP is irrelevant once it's at the browser, and it also complicates the HTML when trying to read it in order to help. I'm sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @DavidThomas I understand now sorry. Please see updated code block. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all the `input` elements within the closest `tr` tag, and remove the readonly attribute of each of them like this:

```js
function UpdateTableRow(object){
    inputs = object.closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
    }
}
```

Equally, the reverse (make entire row readonly again) can be done almost identically:

```js
function LockTableRow(object){
    inputs = object.closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].setAttribute('readonly','true');
    }
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted it to do. Thank you!